# Problem with biblatex /printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

Tags: biblatex, compilation-error

I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence 
<recently read> \less 

l.58 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

I am using Overleaf.

My `main.tex` file is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, citestyle=nature]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

\begin{document}
\subfile{abc} 
...

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

If I remove `[heading=bibintoc]` then the error moves on to the next line, so I'm not sure it really has to do with `\printbibliography`. I first assumed that I might not have closed a bracket but I have checked the  `main.tex` file and they are all closed.

My question is: How do I fix this error?

Comment: Welcom to TSE. I suggest that you post a minimal working example.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for reminding me. I've found it difficult to make a (not) working example and it seems the error has nothing to do with my packages and must be hidden somewhere in the text body

Comment: If I had to guess the problem is not with your text but with one of your `.bib` entries. It either contains `\less` directly, or a character that is wrongly converted to `\less`. You need to find out which `.bib` entry that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @moewe 's comment:
there was a `\less` (2 actually) in a bib entry. As soon as I deleted that the error disappeared.

with the following files you too can reproduce this error:

`main.tex`:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, citestyle=nature]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
    \addbibresource{thesis.bib}

    \begin{document}

    \cite{xyz}
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
    \end{document}
```

and `thesis.bib`:

```
    @article{xyz,
    author = {Author},
    title = {Title$\less$}
    }
```